# Electron window.webContents.send doesn't work

Tags: electron

main.js

```
mainWindow = new BrowserWindow({ show: false, minWidth: 400, minHeight: 400, webPreferences: {nodeIntegration: true} });
mainWindow.maximize();
mainWindow.loadURL(url.format({
    pathname: path.join(__dirname, '/html/index.html'),
    protocol: 'file:',
    slashes: true
}));
mainWindow.on('closed', function(){
    app.quit();
});
const mainMenu = Menu.buildFromTemplate(mainMenuTemplate);
Menu.setApplicationMenu(mainMenu);

mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show();
    const data = {id: 'checking_for_updates', display: 'none'}
    console.log(data)
    mainWindow.webContents.send('change_display', data) 
})
```

index.html

```
<script>
    const electron = require('electron');
    const ipcRenderer = electron.ipcRenderer;
    ipcRenderer.on('change_display', function (event, data) {
        console.log(data);
        document.getElementById(data.id).style.display=data.display;
    })
</script>
<body>
    <!-- Checking if you can update -->
    <div class="container updating"  id="checking_for_updates" style="display: block">
        <h1 class="updating-text">Checking for updates.</h1>
    </div>
```

it only logs 'data' once so probably the ipcRenderer doesn't run the ipcRenderer.on change_display event. How would I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code here:

```
mainWindow.once('ready-to-show', () => {
    mainWindow.show();
    const data = {id: 'checking_for_updates', display: 'none'}
    console.log(data)
    mainWindow.webContents.send('change_display', data) 
})
```

only sends the `change_display` once. And so you'll see `data` logged once as well.